# How to copy another table's record

Tags: mysql

I have table x, y

Table x

```
Id       name.       wage    
1.       A.          10
2.       B.          12
3.       C.          13
```

Table y

```
Id.      Bonus    
1.       5
3.       6
```

I want to create another table but with the records of table x but in wage i want to add it with bonus so the output like this

```
Id       name.       wagebonus    
1.       A.          15    
2.       B.          12    
3.       C.          19
```

I tried

```
insert into newtable 
select id, name, wage+bonus from x, y
```

But failed

Comment: @Arulkumar no that was the "numbered" list being renumbered on output. Now that it is code formatted the values make sense.

Comment: @Arulkumar i want to sum the values of wage with bonus by their respective record, so the one record that not has  bonus not summed but still showed

Comment: @Frd But for `C`, 13 + 6 = 19, how it will be 18 ?

Comment: @Arulkumar sorry i mean 19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a new table, you need a `CREATE TABLE` command, not just an `INSERT`. The other problem with your query is that it doesn't take account of the fact that a person may not get a bonus, so you need to use a `LEFT JOIN` instead of an `INNER JOIN` to ensure all rows from `x` end up in the new table. This will do what you want:

```
CREATE TABLE newtable AS
SELECT x.Id, x.name, x.wage + COALESCE(y.bonus, 0) AS wagebonus
FROM x
LEFT JOIN y ON y.Id = x.Id;
SELECT * FROM newtable ORDER BY Id;
```

Output:

```
Id  name    wagebonus
1   A       15
2   B       12
3   C       19
```

Note that creating a new table for this is probably overkill. You could do the same with a `VIEW`, including adding an `ORDER BY` clause if required:

```
CREATE VIEW newview AS
SELECT x.Id, x.name, x.wage + COALESCE(y.bonus, 0) AS wagebonus
FROM x
LEFT JOIN y ON y.Id = x.Id
ORDER BY Id;
SELECT * FROM newview
```

Output is the same as above.

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gRrhzrL8mksRDpa9XfAN34/4)

Comment: Thanks:), i tried that but why the output sorted from highest to lowest?

Comment: @Frd with no `ORDER BY`, output order is random. Just add `ORDER BY Id` to the `SELECT`. See my edit.

Comment: I can't see that views serve any useful purpose in MySQL. If a table is overkill, then a query should suffice.

Comment: @Strawberry the one place I think they can make sense is where in MySQL 8+ you might use a CTE so that you can save yourself from repeating a complicated subquery multiple times inside another query.

Comment: @Strawberry and Nick views with check option are great to simulate/emulate the check contrainst under MySQL 8.0.16 of so.. i geuss that is MySQL’s best feature or better said usage of a VIEW